# How to use QMutex properly in derived classes?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the following classes (simplified) :

```
class BaseJob : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   QMutex *getMutex() const {
       return &mutex;
   }
virtual ~BaseJob() = 0;

private:
   static QMutex mutex;
};

class Worker1 : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Worker1(QMutex *mutex) : m_mutex(mutex) {}
public slots:
   void work() {
      QMutexLocker lock(m_mutex);
       qInfo() << "worker1 is running";
   }
private:
   QMutex *m_mutex;
};

class Worker2 : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Worker2(QMutex *mutex) : m_mutex(mutex) {}
public slots:
   void work() {
      QMutexLocker lock(m_mutex);
      qInfo() << "worker2 is running";
   }
private:
   QMutex *m_mutex;
};

class Job1 : public BaseJob
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Job1() : m_worker(new Worker1(this->getMutex())) {
       connect(this, SIGNAL(doWork()),
               m_worker, SLOT(work()));
       connect(&m_thread, SIGNAL(finished()),
               m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
       m_worker->moveToThread(&m_thread);
       m_thread.start();
   }
   void work() {
       emit doWork();
   }
   virtual ~Job1() {
       m_thread.quit();
       m_thread.wait();
   }
signals:
   void doWork();

private:
   QThread m_thread;
   Worker1 *m_worker;
};

class Job2 : public BaseJob
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Job2() : m_worker(new Worker2(this->getMutex())) {
       connect(this, SIGNAL(doWork()),
               m_worker, SLOT(work()));
       connect(&m_thread, SIGNAL(finished()),
               m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
       m_worker->moveToThread(&m_thread);
       m_thread.start();
   }
   void work() {
       emit doWork();
   }
   virtual ~Job2() {
       m_thread.quit();
       m_thread.wait();
   }
signals:
   void doWork();

private:
   QThread m_thread;
   Worker2 *m_worker;
};
```

and then i call the jobs using :

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    m_job1->work();
    m_job2->work();
}
```

Workers need to have a public slot, `work()` that should be protected by a critical section to prevent concurrent write access to the same file.

So far, i have added a `QMutex` in the base class `BaseJob` so i can pass a reference to this mutex, through `Worker1` and `Worker2` ctor and finally inside `work()` function.

And it works but is there a better approach to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you not like about the approach you described?

Comment: Why don't you put the `QMutex` in the class that has the critical section? and then document that class as thread-safe. A static `QMutex` looks a little odd to me, but maybe because I am missing context here...

Comment: 1) you're using QMutexLocker wrong, you need to give it a name to stop the lock going out of scope straight away, i.e. `QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);` 2) it's a bit weird to have a static member variable. Maybe make a struct with the mutex and the object you need to be protected, and pass it in the constructor?

Comment: 1) i have mistyped the line and i have edited my question to correct this. Thanks. 2 ) Basically, i use this static variable so that derived classes refer to the same mutex and then i can pass the reference to their workers so they can hold the lock. Why is it weird ? Should i use a plain global variable instead ?

Comment: Your code is lacking some context.  A mutex should typically have the same storage specifiers as the data it's protecting.  Right now you have a mutex but don't describe the data that it should be protecting.  Is that data `class` data or per-instance data?

Comment: The critical section should prevents concurrent write access to a file that is written from a - kind of - logger class . Let's say we have a class Logger with a `void log(const QString &log)` function that is not thread safe, so in `work1()`, i need to protect the `Logger().log("some logs")` calls.

Comment: I have edited my question to provide a better context.